# Strange behaviour in code exection in java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I face strange execution behaviors in login test methods. I run this code Under selenium Grid. and Grid is configured as a standalone server. So, first I start the selenium grid(Hub\Node) using the batch file to execute by tests.

Following is my class and specs.
code: 
1. pojDataSource.java:

```
    public class pojDataSource {

   private static WebElement element = null;
   private static List<WebElement> elements = null;

   public static WebElement txt_UserName(WebDriver driver){ 
     driver.findElement(By.id("txtUserName")).clear();
     element = driver.findElement(By.id("txtUserName"));
     return element;
      }

   public static WebElement txt_Password(WebDriver driver){     
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).clear();
    element = driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword"));
    return element;
  }
}
```

2. clsConstant.java:

   ```
   public class clsConstant {
       public static final String URL = "http://localhost:1234/";  
       public static final String Username = "username";
       public static final String Password = "password";
   }
   ```
3. ModuleTest.java:

   ```
      public class ModuleTest {

      public RemoteWebDriver mDriver = null;
      public DesiredCapabilities mCapability = new DesiredCapabilities() ;
      public WebElement mWebElement = null;
      public String mBaseURL = clsConstant.URL;    
      public static clsExcelSampleData mAddConnectorXls;    

     @Test
     public void beforeMethod()  throws Exception {

     WebDriverWait wdw =null;                
     mCapability.setCapability("platform", org.openqa.selenium.Platform.WINDOWS);
     mCapability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
     mCapability.setVersion("45.0.2");
     mDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/"), mCapability);
     mDriver.get(mBaseURL);                                                
     mDriver.manage().window().maximize();
     pojDataSource.txt_UserName(mDriver).sendKeys(clsConstant.Username ) ;
     pojDataSource.txt_Password(mDriver).sendKeys(clsConstant.Password ) ;
     pojDataSource.btn_LogIn(mDriver).click();       
     }
   ```

When I execute the code in DEBUG mode in eclipese IDE it shows me the strange behaviors. First it start browser and open the mBaseURL successful with login screen. After loading page it shows default userName\password in browser.

Now when debug point comes to pojDataSource.txt_UserName(mDriver).sendKeys(clsConstant.Username ); line. By pressing F5 my debug point goes to pojDataSource.txt_Password(); line and it fetch wrong password and script execution fails. I worry about how this will be happens if my debug point is at username but still it goes to fetch value of password?

Tried solutions:
1. As I use Firefox browser to run test. I clear my password from browser catch.

Answer (score 0):

Recheck the WebElements IDs and make sure they are reachable by WebDriver while debugging. Also try to avoid using 'static' to WebElements. Take a look on Page Objects Pattern.

Comment: Thanks Lucrib. but The same code I'm able to run perfectly before Re-Import this project in my new Eclipse version.